# Import Point Data to Oracle through FME with considering few other Point file attribute

Tags: fme-form

I have three Point file (*.mif); Pole, Switch and Transformer

Pole is the main feature which will be my Output, but I need additional information within pole layer attribute using information from Switch and Transformer layer.

- Pole layer have 3 attribute field: PoleID, Switch and Transformer
- The attribute I will use from Switch layer is SwitchType – (i.e. LV/HV etc.)
- From transformer, I want only the status of availability within pole (Yes / No )

### Condition:

a. I want to search any Switch which is available within 2mtrs buffer to a Pole

b. If switch identified, then I will read the attribute field of the switch; SwitchType – (i.e. LV/HV etc.) and update in the particular Pole attribute in the Switch field.

c. For Transformer, I want to search any Transformer which is available within 2mtrs buffer to a Pole

d. If Transformer Identified, then the Pole attribute field (Transformer) will updated with Yes otherwise No

e. Finally all the poles with updated attributes will import to Oracle

Can you help me to update these attributes using a different point layer?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the NeighborFinder transformer. This would let you search for items within a 2 metre radius and would add the attributes of any feature it finds within that distance.

For example:

[image: workspace]

The trick is to get the output from both MATCHED and UNMATCHED output ports, as not every pole will have a switch or transformer within your 2m distance.

I've used separate NeighborFinders for each search. I think this will work better. With one NeighborFinder you'd have to handle the Switch/Transformer as a list and this would not be as simple.

Answer (score 0):

If the switch attribute on pole matches the value of switch found within 2 mtrs, I would perform a join of switch table to pole using switch as key field for one to one join keep only matching.
Then the same for transformer.
Using copy attribute transformer each time to end up with one table to load into oracle.